How do I download blockchain data from amazon s3 with aws cli?
Amazon says that they have made blockchain publically available on the net:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/access-bitcoin-and-ethereum-open-datasets-for-cross-chain-analytics/
Is it possible to download it with aws CLI? I am able to list something there like this:
aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://aws-public-blockchain/v1.0/eth/

indeed I don't understand how to get it to my computer, all tutorials I could quickly reach, end up using some special software. So how do I download it?

You could use something like aws s3 sync --no-sign-request s3://aws-public-blockchain/v1.0/eth/ . to transfer all of the objects to your local machine.  Be aware, you'll need about 4 TiB of free storage space locally.

Dear @AnonCoward, please post it as an answer, please, so i can accept it.
